# Почему visual studio 2019 выбивает ошибку?

Tags: c++

Имеется такой код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    //Default settings
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    using namespace std;


    int x; char value[2];

    //

    cout << "Введите число: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "В какой величине введенное число?";
    gets(value);


}
```

В итоге VS выбивает такого рода ошибку, по какой причине это может происходить. Еще пишет, что ошибка на 25 строке, а 25ой строки даже нет...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `gets` убрали из языка, так как небезопасно, используйте `gets_s`

Comment: @VTT, напишите ответ

Comment: если в VS работаете попробуйте gets_s();

Answer (score 1):

Функция `gets` удалена из стандартной библиотеки. Вместо функции `gets` следует использовать функцию `fgets`. Только помните, что у них немножко разное поведение - `fgets` сохраняет в строке символ перевода строки.